# Why or how to prove that the infinitesimal symmetries of a differential equation form a Lie algebra?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetry

Given a partial differential equation, after computing the Lie point symmetries of this PDE, means a one-parameter group (Lie group) of transformation that leaves the set of solutions of the PDE invariant using Lie's theorem (infinitesimal criterion of symmetry), this one parameter group is generated by a vector field (infinitesimal symmetry) see Olver's book application of Lie groups to differential equations, but he does not prove my following question.
While computing these vector fields, I want to prove that they form a Lie algebra.

Comment: The symmetry group gives a local lie group, this allows you to calculate commutators for "small" group elements and differentiating this commutator along curves of group elements at the identity give you the Lie bracket